# How to change keyboard settings of the active user using udev and setxkbmap?

Tags: xorg, udev, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have a usb keyboard that I plug in into my desktop at work. While using it tend to manually set the following **setxkbmap** option:

```
setxkbmap -option compose:ralt
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl
```

Since I do it frequently I wanted to automate the process by using a **udev** rule. The following rule matches the event when I plug-in the keyboard:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVER=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0023", RUN+="/home/cutuchiqueno/.local/bin/kbd_udev", OWNER="cutuchiqueno"
```

the script which is RUN contains the three lines from the beginning of this question:

```
#!/bin/bash
setxkbmap -option compose:ralt
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl
setxkbmap -option ctrl:swap_lwin_lctl
echo `date +%T` >> /home/cutuchiqueno/udevtest
```

(I added the last line just for debugging purpose). Unfortunately the options are not chainged. I can imagine that is has something to do with environment parameters though I don not really know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Two modifications made this particular case working:

the `kbd` script  needed a `DISPLAY:0.0` addition

the udev rule reacted to an event that was too early. I changed subsystem to `input`.

and everything worked well.